# Getting different session objects in JAX-RS

Tags: jax-rs, httpsession

I have this JAX-RS code that works well when the request comes from different browsers (such as Chrome and IE):

```
@Path("/")
public class LoginService {
    
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @POST
    @Path("/proclogin")
    public Response processLogin(String userid) {
            
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
                
        System.out.println("Got session " + session);  // <-- print session object

        return Response.ok().build();

}
```

The `session` object that is printed is different when the browsers are different.

But if I open a new tab in Chrome and make the request again, the `session` object is the same for both tabs.

I need the user to be able to use the application in the same browser opening different tabs using different userids. I also need to store session information on the server side, but if the session object is the same I cannot achieve that. How can this be supported in JAX-RS?

Comment: You're completely missing the exact meaning of "REST". Handle it in the client side not in the server side.

Comment: Thanks, solved it with a different token in the client side